# not getting the SOAP response

Tags: c#, soap

My SOAP request works - hits the server and displays my request in the server logs  and sends the response but I am unable to read the response with my codes (C# & ASP.NET) below.Am I missing something?

```
    try
    {
        string url = "http://a.b.c.d/ABC/services/DOMFlightAvailability?wsdl";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.KeepAlive = false;
        req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        req.Method = "POST";

        string request = "<Request>"
                  + "<Origin>BOM</Origin>"
                  + "<Destination>BLR</Destination>"
                  + "<DepartDate>2014-11-15</DepartDate>"
                  + "<ReturnDate>2014-11-15</ReturnDate>"
                  + "<AdultPax>1</AdultPax>"
                  + "<ChildPax>1</ChildPax>"
                  + "<InfantPax>1</InfantPax>"
                  + "<Currency>INR</Currency>"
                  + "<Clientid>123</Clientid>"
                  + "<Clientpassword>123</Clientpassword>"
                  + "<Clienttype>123</Clienttype>"
                  + "<Preferredclass>E</Preferredclass>"
                  + "<mode>ONE</mode>"
                  + "<PreferredAirline>AI,G8,IC,6E,9W,S2,IT,9H,I7,SG</PreferredAirline>"
              + "</Request>";           

        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("xmlRequest=" + request + "");
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
        Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Response.Write(responseText);
        lblResult.Text = responseText;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
```

This is my other way of doing it - hits the server and trasmits the response but I am still unable to get the response data

```
    try
    {

        DOMFlightAvailabilityPortTypeClient obj = new DOMFlightAvailabilityPortTypeClient();
        string req = "<Request>"
                + "<Origin>BOM</Origin>"
                + "<Destination>DEL</Destination>"
                + "<DepartDate>2014-11-20</DepartDate>"
                + "<ReturnDate>2014-12-21</ReturnDate>"
                + "<AdultPax>1</AdultPax>"
                + "<ChildPax>0</ChildPax>"
                + "<InfantPax>0</InfantPax>"
                + "<Currency>INR</Currency>"
                + "<Clientid>123</Clientid>"
                + "<Clientpassword>123</Clientpassword>"
                + "<Clienttype>123</Clienttype>"
                + "<Preferredclass>E</Preferredclass>"
                + "<mode>ONE</mode>"
                + "<PreferredAirline>AI,G8,IC,6E,9W,S2,IT,9H,I7,SG</PreferredAirline>"
            + "</Request>";

        string str = obj.getAvailability(req);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(str);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(str)));
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Where is your server side code?

Comment: stated above is my server side code

Comment: No its client side code.

Comment: i have hard coded the data for my testing purpose in the server side C#, its just that I am not getting response even though the client server is sending the response ...

Comment: So can you show the server side code where request is processed and response message is sent back for above code? Also what does it mean not getting response - error or getting empty string?

Comment: can i have ur email so that i can send the complete code

Comment: No. Add shortened code parts here that it could be easy to understand what you doing or better to recreate situation.

Comment: OK, I have a SOAP request and it sends data to the server - works fine, now the same server responds my SOAP request but I am not able to get the response with the codes above. So my question is that am I missing something to get the response ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add code there.

Comment: Can you understand what I want that you add in your question? I dont need client side code - you already added it...that code that created request and sends to server is client side. What Iam asking you is SERVER side code. The code where request is received, processed and response is created.

Comment: Also "IAm not able to get response" so what are you getting? Exception? If that so what is the error? No exception, so what is the content of your `str` variable in line `string str = obj.getAvailability(req);` when debugging?

Comment: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (502) Server Hangup.

Comment: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Comment: So you do get response - error message. Now google for appropriate error because I give up on trying to pull all required information from you.

Comment: why give up before even trying it??

Comment: Before trying what? Ask you to add server side code? I ALREADY DID THAT...3 times.